# To declare or not local variables in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Which is better way of writing `foo()`?
 
`foo1()` or `foo2()`?
Better in terms of:

1. Performance
2. Memory consumption
3. Variable/Object entropy

Assuming other factors are taken care of.
ex: the variable is not used at multiple places within the function, etc.

```
        function f1() {
            return 10;
        }

        function f2() {
            return 20;
        }

        function foo1() {
            return f1() === f2();
        }

        function foo2() {
            var i = f1();
            var j = f2();
            return i === j;
        }
```

Comment: See for yourself; http://jsperf.com/so-30611329

Comment: Memory consumption will be only momentary so unlikely any meaningful difference there.  Performance is also likely not much different, though `foo1()` could have a tiny advantage.  The differences here are so unlikely  to be significant that you should write the code the way that would make it the cleanest and easiest to understand and maintain.  If this is all there is to it, then I see no advantage of `foo2()` over `foo1()`so I'd go with the more compact `foo1()`.

Comment: What definition of entropy do you use?

Comment: @Bergi, I meant by entropy, the number of objects in memory at any given point of time and the complexity associated with the management of their states. Coming from `C++` world, I try to reduce as much as possible creation of objects. Wondering how it is to be in `JavaScript` from best practices perspective.

Comment: thanks, @limelights, I didn't know about the performance workbench.

Comment: @jfriend00 thanks, your comment is helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not an expert on this, but I'll try my best..

For performance, as mentioned on the comment you could use [jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/)..

For memory consumption, I believe `foo1()` is better, because you don't need to create new variable..

For variable entropy, I'm not sure how to answer this point, since I believe you don't really need those variables.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

It actually Depends.

`foo1()` - If you need to use `f1()` and `f2()` only ONCE in the function then foo1() will be better. As using additional variables to keep the same results doesn't make any sense and also they will cover some memory (very tiny amount). So this additional cost can be eliminated by using functions directly.

`foo2()` - If you to use `f1()` and `f2()` multiple times in the function then `foo2()` will be better, as storing function value in a ONE variable and using it many times would be far better than calling Function again and again for Same results.
But yes, If your functions contains logic and Result of function can change any time then obviously you will need to call function everytime.

Comment: "*Assuming the variable is not used at multiple places within the function*"

Comment: Still it answers the question - foo1() is better

Comment: But you don't give any reason why?